# "Boku mo tsurete!"

Tags: phrases

Does sentence "Boku mo tsurete" mean only "Take me" or "Lead me", or it could also mean "Follow me" or "Come with", based on context? Thanks!

Comment: "Follow me" would be something like 僕に続いて (Boku ni tuzuite), never 僕も連れて. Did you mishear?

Comment: `Does sentence "Boku mo tsurete" mean only "Take me"` -- It should be 「僕も連れて(い)って」(Boku mo tsurete(i)tte).   `it could also mean "Follow me" or "Come with"` <-- "Come with" って？

Comment: この場合はただの入力ミスかもしれませんが、”come with”は一応スラングで、意味は”come with me”になります。くだけた会話では”wanna come with?”のように割と頻繁に使われると思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the context is like

> A: これから山田さんと田中さん家へ行く(Kore kara yamadasan to tanakasanchi e iku)
>
> B: 僕も連れて (Boku mo tsurete)

it would be like

> A: I'm going to Tanaka's place with Yamada
>
> B: Take me with you